# Sharing data using Laravel View Composers with paginated view not working

Tags: laravel, view, composer-php

I want to share some data to multiple views in which I use View Composers concept of Laravel like this:
In AppServiceProvider.php

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view)
    {
        /* SHARED DATA */
        $socialLinks = $settings = $categories =  array();

        if(Schema::hasTable('social_links')) {
            $socialLinksObj = new SocialLinkService();
            $socialLinks = $socialLinksObj->all();
        }

        if(Schema::hasTable('settings')) {
            $settingService = new SettingService();
            $settings = $settingService->list();
        }

        /* END SHARED DATA */
        $view->with([
            'socialLinks' => $socialLinks,
            'settings' => $settings,
        ]);
    });
```

The above code is working fine as it share data to every view, but I have same views which have paginated data like this query:

```
Inventories::with($relations)->latest()->paginate($pagination)
```

in this page I have data which I share from view composer as you can see in below screenshot

[image]

but when I go to next page shared data not available.

[image: ie]

what should I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: How is this question related to Composer? Please don't use irrelevant tags on your question

Answer (score 0):

So, first this is not a very good use of a view composer. The code runs for every single view blade that gets rendered and is highly inefficient.

If you need to share a couple of pieces of data I would put this code in your `AppServiceProvider::boot()` method:

```php
        /* SHARED DATA */
        $socialLinks = $settings = $categories =  array();

        if(Schema::hasTable('social_links')) {
            $socialLinksObj = new SocialLinkService();
            $socialLinks = $socialLinksObj->all();
        }

        if(Schema::hasTable('settings')) {
            $settingService = new SettingService();
            $settings = $settingService->list();
        }

        /* END SHARED DATA */
        View::share('socialLinks', $socialLinks);
        View::share('settings', $settings);
```

And then your variables are available on every view as `$socialLinks` and `$settings`. Just remember that if at any point in your code you pass another `socialLinks` or `settings` to your View it will be overwritten by the last one set.